# cmake: Compile files in defined order, not alphabetically

Tags: cmake

I have identified a couple of cpp files that take significantly longer than others to compile. When compiling in parallel (`make -j`), I want the corresponding jobs to be started first.

```
set(
SOURCES
expensive.hpp
expensive.cpp
bla.hpp
bla.cpp
foo.hpp
foo.cpp
)

add_library(myproject STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

Still, cmake produces a Makefile that is sorted alphabetically. Is there any way to influence this?

I am using cmake 3.7.1.

Comment: Unrelated, but still: Try Ninja-build instead of make if you are seeking speed.

Comment: You could try segregating your fat files into a static library and build that library as a dependency.